# How do I open a Finder sidebar folder via AppleScript?

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, finder

I have a bash script which will be run on a Mac via ssh. The script requires a particular network drive to already be mounted. On the Mac, I mount this drive by opening a folder "JPLemme" on that drive in Finder. This mounts the drive until the Mac goes to sleep at night.

Obviously, Finder isn't available via ssh, so I want to create an AppleScript that will simulate what I do through the GUI. I've tried:

```
tell application "Finder"
activate
open "JPLemme"
end tell
```

I receive the following error:

```
execution error: Finder got an error: Can't get "JPLemme". (-1728)
```

I assume I'm missing something obvious, but Google has failed me. I would also be willing to entertain better solutions like mounting the drive directly; I've avoided that approach because I don't want the Mac to choke trying to mount the drive a second time after I've already mounted it in an unexpected way. (I don't really like Macs or AppleScript...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your network volume should have a domain attached to it of some kind. So, "JPLemme.domain.com". I use the following chunk of code to get onto a network volume that is password protected:

```
    tell application "Finder"
       try
          set theServer to mount volume "smb://path/to/volume" as username "YourUserName" with password "YourPassword" 
--Please note here that this is a plain string without any built-in security. Use at your own risk.
       on error
          set VolumeCount to (get count of disks)
          repeat with x from 1 to VolumeCount
             set thisVolume to disk x
             if name of thisVolume is "JPLemme" then
                set theServer to thisVolume
                exit repeat
             end if
          end repeat
       end try
    end tell
```

You can clean it up as necessary, but that's the core of it. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

At it's very core, all that is really needed is the following:

```
Tell Application "Finder"
   Mount Volume "smb://username:password@server/sub/directory"
End Tell
```

But what is used will depend largely on network environment and errors returned.